# How can I test if QueueClient can successfully connect to an Azure Service Bus Queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient to connect to a known good queue that I've setup in Azure Service Bus using the connection string format sb://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/

But, our draconian firewall/acl rules apply even to DEV and TEST machines.

Is there a way that I can run a test in the code to see if the Client was able to successfully connect to the Endpoint?

Comment: Sorry mate, I am not going to give you the answer you want so I am doing it as a comment.  If you look at the code on https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus you will see that they have moved some things to `internal class`, including things that would have allowed us to check if the queue existed or was available.

Comment: ahh rats... yeah I guess that happens. As a dev in my org, I am always in that situation where I have to PROVE first that it's really a connectivity issue. The rest of our org looks at the cloud like it's witches, so I have to have all the info going in.

Comment: Try send empty message and process exceptions:

Comment: Try send empty message and process exceptions:

    bool   Listening = false;
    try {
            queueClient.SendAsync(new     Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message()).Wait();
          Listening = true;
        } catch (Exception exc) {
          Listening = false;
          for (Exception e = exc; e != null; e = e.InnerException) {
            if (e is System.UnauthorizedAccessException) {
              Listening = true;
              break;
            }
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Azure Functions you can make a message/Email alerts to Service Bus for knowing the QueueClient can connect successfully

Comment: This is an interesting idea but it would be more beneficial if you provided a bit more of an explanation and even some example code to go with it.

Answer (score -2):

You can run your code outside of your firewall so that the connection will be allowed.

For instance, if you have a web app, you can simply host it in an App Service plan and see if the connection is successful. You also could stand up a VM, host it in an Azure Function, Service Fabric, Cloud Services, etc.